# Reshaping from wide to long and vice versa (multistate/survival analysis dataset)

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape

I am trying to reshape the following dataset with `reshape()`, without much results.

The starting dataset is in "wide" form, with each id described through one row. The dataset is intended to be adopted for carry out Multistate analyses (a generalization of Survival Analysis).

Each person is recorded for a given overall time span. During this period the subject can experience a number of transitions among states (for simplicity let us fix to two the maximum number of distinct states that can be visited). The first visited state is `s1 = 1, 2, 3, 4`. The person stays within the state for `dur1` time periods, and the same applies for the second visited state `s2`:

```
   id    cohort    s1     dur1     s2     dur2     
     1      1        3      4       2      5       
     2      0        1      4       4      3
```

The dataset in long format which I woud like to obtain is:

```
id    cohort    s    
1       1       3
1       1       3
1       1       3
1       1       3
1       1       2
1       1       2
1       1       2
1       1       2
1       1       2
2       0       1
2       0       1
2       0       1
2       0       1
2       0       4
2       0       4
2       0       4
```

In practice, each id has `dur1 + dur2` rows, and `s1` and `s2` are melted in a single variable `s`.

How would you do this transformation? Also, how would you cmoe back to the original dataset "wide" form?

Many thanks!

```
dat <- cbind(id=c(1,2), cohort=c(1, 0), s1=c(3, 1), dur1=c(4, 4), s2=c(2, 4), dur2=c(5, 3))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reshape()` for the first step, but then you need to do some more work. Also, `reshape()` needs a `data.frame()` as its input, but your sample data is a matrix.

Here's how to proceed:

1. `reshape()` your data from wide to long:

   ```
   dat2 <- reshape(data.frame(dat), direction = "long", 
                   idvar = c("id", "cohort"),
                   varying = 3:ncol(dat), sep = "")
   dat2
   #       id cohort time s dur
   # 1.1.1  1      1    1 3   4
   # 2.0.1  2      0    1 1   4
   # 1.1.2  1      1    2 2   5
   # 2.0.2  2      0    2 4   3
   ```
2. "Expand" the resulting `data.frame` using `rep()`

   ```
   dat3 <- dat2[rep(seq_len(nrow(dat2)), dat2$dur), c("id", "cohort", "s")]
   dat3[order(dat3$id), ]
   #         id cohort s
   # 1.1.1    1      1 3
   # 1.1.1.1  1      1 3
   # 1.1.1.2  1      1 3
   # 1.1.1.3  1      1 3
   # 1.1.2    1      1 2
   # 1.1.2.1  1      1 2
   # 1.1.2.2  1      1 2
   # 1.1.2.3  1      1 2
   # 1.1.2.4  1      1 2
   # 2.0.1    2      0 1
   # 2.0.1.1  2      0 1
   # 2.0.1.2  2      0 1
   # 2.0.1.3  2      0 1
   # 2.0.2    2      0 4
   # 2.0.2.1  2      0 4
   # 2.0.2.2  2      0 4
   ```

You can get rid of the funky row names too by using `rownames(dat3) <- NULL`.

### Update: Retaining the ability to revert to the original form

In the example above, since we dropped the "time" and "dur" variables, it isn't possible to directly revert to the original dataset. If you feel this is something you would need to do, I suggest keeping those columns in and creating another `data.frame` with the subset of the columns that you need if required.

Here's how:

Use `aggregate()` to get back to "dat2":

```
aggregate(cbind(s, dur) ~ ., dat3, unique)
#   id cohort time s dur
# 1  2      0    1 1   4
# 2  1      1    1 3   4
# 3  2      0    2 4   3
# 4  1      1    2 2   5
```

Wrap `reshape()` around that to get back to "dat1". Here, in one step:

```
reshape(aggregate(cbind(s, dur) ~ ., dat3, unique), 
        direction = "wide", idvar = c("id", "cohort"))
#   id cohort s.1 dur.1 s.2 dur.2
# 1  2      0   1     4   4     3
# 2  1      1   3     4   2     5
```

Comment: Very neat answer, thank you very much! May I ask you how to carry out the "reverse" operation? (i.e. getting `dat` starting from an initial `dat3` matrix).

Comment: @Stezzo, see my update. It basically involves using `aggregate()` and `reshape()`, but you would need to not drop any columns when creating "dat3".

Comment: The answer is perfect, thanks again. I have posted the "reversal" problem (long --> wide) in case we do not have a starting wide dataset for using your above `aggregate()` strategy. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296918/complex-long-to-wide-data-transformation-conditionally-splitting-a-time-varying)

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better ways, but this might work.

```
df <- read.table(text = '
   id    cohort    s1     dur1     s2     dur2     
     1      1        3      4       2      5       
     2      0        1      4       4      3',
header=TRUE)

hist <- matrix(0, nrow=2, ncol=9)
hist

for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {

hist[i,] <- c(rep(df[i,3], df[i,4]), rep(df[i,5], df[i,6]), rep(0, (9 - df[i,4] - df[i,6])))

}

hist

hist2 <- cbind(df[,1:2], hist)
colnames(hist2) <- c('id', 'cohort', paste('x', seq_along(1:9), sep=''))

library(reshape2)

hist3 <- melt(hist2, id.vars=c('id', 'cohort'), variable.name='x', value.name='state')

hist4 <- hist3[order(hist3$id, hist3$cohort),]
hist4

hist4 <- hist4[ , !names(hist4) %in% c("x")]

hist4 <- hist4[!(hist4[,2]==0 & hist4[,3]==0),]
```

Gives:

```
   id cohort state
1   1      1     3
3   1      1     3
5   1      1     3
7   1      1     3
9   1      1     2
11  1      1     2
13  1      1     2
15  1      1     2
17  1      1     2
2   2      0     1
4   2      0     1
6   2      0     1
8   2      0     1
10  2      0     4
12  2      0     4
14  2      0     4
```

Of course, if you have more than two states per id then this would have to be modified (and it might have to be modified if you have more than two cohorts).  For example, I suppose with 9 sample periods one person could be in the following sequence of states:

```
1 3 2 4 3 4 1 1 2
```